# Storing trailing zeroes in database with JPA and Oracle

Tags: spring, oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa, scale

I need to store prices in my database. I'm using JPA, so I've got a model like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="price")   
    private float price;
}
```

The problem is that when I fill price form inputs with values like "4.20", on my Oracle database I get "4.2", losing the trailing zero.

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:** Since I'm using JPA, I have to avoid writing queries in native Oracle dialect. To store products (with their prices) I simply write something like `em.persist(product)`, where em is the EntityManager

Comment: You want to store prices as a float/double - that is generally not a good idea. I suggest switching to integer, and use a (maybe implicit) currency + currency exponent. 4.20 -> 420 (USD,2)

Answer (score 6):

You can't solve it, and I'd suggest it's not a problem. That's just how Oracle stores `NUMBER` values: with the least precision needed. If you entered the price as `4.00` it would be stored as `4`.

Note that Java won't default to two decimals either when displaying the value. You need to specify the number of decimal places.

And, if possible, I'd use `BigDecimal` instead of `float` for the price. The `float` type isn't precise. An alternative is to use one of the integer types (`int` or `long`) and manage the decimal places yourself.

To format the price for display in your Java code, use `String.format("%.2f", price)`.

To format the price in an Oracle query, use [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2113.htm):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(price, '999999990.00'), etc.
```

Choose the number of placeholders that's best for you, and note that Oracle will put an extra space at the beginning of the result. It's meant to hold a minus sign if the number is negative, but for zero/positive it's a space. To get rid of the space use the `FM` modifier in the `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(price, 'FM999999990.00'), etc.
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try to use BigDecimal. But I didn't understand where should I write `String.format("%.2f", price)` in my code. Another problem is that, since I'm using JPA, I avoid writing queries in native Oracle dialect. To store products (with their prices) I simply write something like `em.persist(product)`, where `em` is the EntityManager.

Comment: +1 but it's not about Oracle storage format, only about output representation.

Comment: Kurt - I'm not familiar with JPA (I mostly do .NET MVC), but from a bit of Googling I cobbled together this annotation that could work for your `price` value. Line 1: `@Column(name="price", precision=12, scale=2)`. Line 2: `private BigDecimal price;`. If it works as I hope it does, you may not need to do the `String.format` thing. For all I know the annotation may work for a `float` too. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @EdGibbs I tried this solution but I keep getting just a "4.2" value on the database. That could have been a nice solution...

Comment: @KurtBourbaki - Oracle will store it as "4.2" no matter what you do. There's no getting around it. What's important is having the value display as 4.20 on your forms without having to do all kinds of special programming, and hopefully some combination of JPA annotations can make that happen.

Comment: @EdGibbs Unfortunately that annotation didn't help neither outside the database: I display 4.2 as well :(